# Extract pattern from image

Tags: image, background, pattern-matching, photoshop

Is there any way to figure out the pattern from an image?
I need it so that I could create a smaller image from it to repeat so that I could have a background pattern.

p.s: Don't mind the 2 different colors, I just need the almost transparent lines pattern figured out.

[image: Image with Pattern]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a white and black repeating version of the pattern.

[image]
[image]

What did I do?

1. Copied some of the top portion of your image
2. Pasted it into a mask on a solid white layer
3. Added a photo under the layer to simulate the finished result
4. Inverted the mask
5. Adjusted the levels on the mask until I got an effect that was similar to your example
6. Cropped the image down to one pattern so it would be repeatable
7. Hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> <kbd>CNTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> to save for web and saved it as a 24-bit PNG
8. Then inverted the white layer to black and saved for web again.

Does that seem to be what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would use levels to get it to almost black & white.

1. Use sliders to get the lightest grey as light as possible
2. use the highlight/Shadow eyedropers within the levels palette to get it even closer
3. Use threshold to get it the rest of the way.

Take a look at the image below to see if what I described is what you are wanting.

[image: Pattern using levels/Threshold]